# Sitecore 10.3 installation using Sitecore Instance Manager

Tags: sim

Has anyone tried to install sitecore 10 versions using SIM, Sitecore Instance Manager?
Does this support it?

---

Was facing the issue with policies.
[image]

The policies should look like above to proceed with installation issues from SIM

More details here
https://vladtalkstech.com/2014/03/change-powershell-machinepolicy-execution-policy-windows-server-2012r2.html

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded the latest version of Sitecore Install Manager (SIM) from here: [Sitecore Install Manager](http://dl.sitecore.net/updater/sim/v2/)

After initial setup, you have an option to "Get Sitecore", which opens up a dialog box showing the versions of Sitecore that you can download and install. As you can see in the image below, it currently lists all versions up to Sitecore 10.3.0 (Initial Release). I am guessing 10.3.1 will be added in the future.

[image: Sitecore Install Manager]

Comment: Thanks Dean, Looks its working... I was facing the issues with policies. Below blog helped me fix it.
https://vladtalkstech.com/2014/03/change-powershell-machinepolicy-execution-policy-windows-server-2012r2.html